# how to pipe output of ps2pdf to zathura

Tags: pipe, pdf, man, zathura

I want to view manpages as pdf. 
I tried the following:

`man -t awk | ps2pdf - - | zathura` (combination of [this](https://appuals.com/convert-man-pages-ps-pdf-format-linux-command-line/) and the last example in the manpage of ps2pdf)

However, zathura just shows me a black window, as if I did not open any file.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `-` as a command line argument to zathura:

```
man -t awk | ps2pdf - - | zathura -
```

as the man page says:

```
zathura displays the given files. If a single hyphen-minus (-) is given
as file name, the content will be read from the standard input.
```